# Touch on screen in windows phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am building an application to find dead pixels on the screen and I get a big problem that I can not solve by myself. My code uses to draw a rectangle on the screen at the point that user touch on.
My XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="Gray">        
        <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="Purple" PointerMoved="digitizerGrid_PointerMoved" PointerReleased="digitizerGrid_PointerReleased">
            <Grid x:Name="digitizerGrid" Visibility="Visible"/>
        </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

and my c# code to handle event:

```
private void digitizerGrid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(myCanvas);
        Point currentContactPt = pt.Position;
        double x2 = currentContactPt.X;
        double y2 = currentContactPt.Y;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
        {
            Width = 50,
            Height = 50,
            StrokeThickness = 20.0,
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x2);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, y2);
        myCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
    }
```

When I touch and fill all the screen like this:
[image]

I get the wrong result image below with black pixel blocks:
[image]

So I can not detect where is dead pixels. What I was wrong?
Thank in advance!